# Getting S3 objects' last modified datetimes with boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, boto

I'm writing a Python script that uploads files to **S3** using `boto` librairy. I only want to upload *changed* files (which I can check by their "last modified" datetimes), but I can't find the Boto API endpoint to get the last modified date.

Comment: See http://mashupguide.net/1.0/html/ch16s07.xhtml towards the bottom. It implies that a bucket has keys and the keys have a `last_modified` attribute. Is that what you're looking for?  Disclaimer: I've not used S3 :)

Comment: Thanks gforture. It's really helpful.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Here's a snippet of Python/boto code that will print the last_modified attribute of all keys in a bucket:

```
>>> import boto
>>> s3 = boto.connect_s3()
>>> bucket = s3.lookup('mybucket')
>>> for key in bucket:
       print key.name, key.size, key.last_modified
index.html 13738 2012-03-13T03:54:07.000Z
markdown.css 5991 2012-03-06T18:32:43.000Z
>>>
```

Comment: For the record this is not perfect; the last_modified is a string, when what you probably want is a datetime

Comment: If you want a DateTime, you can use boto.utils.parse_ts to parse the TZ string and return a DateTime object.

Comment: oddly enough, the parse_ts function does not work with the format returned by key.last_modified i get 

time data 'Fri, 20 Jul 2012 16:57:27 GMT' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'

Comment: Just for future reference, this worked for me: time.strptime(key.last_modified, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')

Comment: It's worth noting that the format returned depends on how you got the key!  Using boto 2.34.0, getting a key from `bucket.get_all_keys()` returns a string like `u'2015-03-16T14:02:50.000Z'`, whereas getting the same key though `bucket.get_key(name)` results in: `'Mon, 16 Mar 2015 14:02:50 GMT'`.  In short: `bucket.get_key(bucket.get_all_keys()[0].name).last_modified == bucket.get_all_keys()[0].last_modified` is `False`.

Comment: That is true.  It's because the S3 service sends the data in two different formats depending on whether you are listing the keys in a bucket or actually doing a HEAD or GET request on a particular key.

Comment: thanks for your good explanation @garnaat

Answer (score 31):

Boto3 returns a datetime object for `LastModified` when you use the the (S3) `Object` python object:

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.last_modified

You shouldn't need to perform any tortuous string manipulations.

To compare `LastModified` to today's date (Python3):

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timezone

today = datetime.now(timezone.utc)

s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name='eu-west-1')

objects = s3.list_objects(Bucket='my_bucket')

for o in objects["Contents"]:
    if o["LastModified"] == today:
        print(o["Key"])
```

You just need to be aware that `LastModifed` is timezone aware, so any date you compare with it must also be timezone aware, hence:

`datetime.now(timezone.utc)`

Comment: Is LastModifed UTC timezone aware always?

Answer (score 18):

For just one s3 object you can use boto client's `head_object()` method which is faster than `list_objects_v2()` for one object as less content is returned. The returned value is `datetime` similar to all boto responses and therefore easy to process.

`head_object()` method comes with other features around modification time of the object which can be leveraged without further calls after `list_objects()` result.

See this :
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.head_object

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
response = client.head_object(Bucket, Key)
datetime_value = response["LastModified"]
```

Comment: I think head_object is an apt call for metadata retrieval.

Answer (score 10):

this is working (tnx to  jdennison from above):

after getting the key from s3:

```
import time
from time import mktime
from datetime import datetime

modified = time.strptime(key.last_modified, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')

#convert to datetime
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(modified))
```

Comment: you answered the wrong issue - the issue is about getting date of s3 files, not about formatting it.

Comment: time data u'2018-06-10T06:31:35.000Z' does not match format '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z'

Answer (score 4):

Convert the last_modified attribute to struct_time as given below

```
import time
for key in bucket.get_all_keys(): 
    time.strptime(key.last_modified[:19], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

This will give a time.struct_time(tm_year, tm_mon, tm_mday, tm_hour, tm_min, tm_sec, tm_wday, tm_yday, tm_isdst) tuple for each key in the S3 bucket

Answer (score 3):

If you're using [Django](https://djangoproject.org) and [django-storages](http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html), you can an **unofficial API** in the *s3boto* backend:

```
>>> from storages.backends.s3boto import _parse_datestring
>>> _parse_datestring("Fri, 20 Jul 2012 16:57:27 GMT")
datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 21, 2, 57, 27)
```

Unfortunately as of django-storages 1.1.5, this gives a naive datetime. You need to use `django.utils.timezone` to create an *aware* version:

```
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> naive = _parse_datestring("Fri, 20 Jul 2012 16:57:27 GMT")
>>> timezone.make_aware(naive, timezone.get_current_timezone())
datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 21, 2, 57, 27, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Australia/Brisbane' EST+10:00:00 STD>)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a [Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48867829/9778755), you can get an [iterator of all objects](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.objects) and then retrieve the `last_modified` attribute of an [`ObjectSummary`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#objectsummary).

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bk = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)

[obj.last_modified for obj in bk.objects.all()][:10]
```

returns

```
[datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 17, 13, 23, 37, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 17, 13, 23, 37, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 17, 13, 23, 38, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 17, 13, 23, 38, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 17, 13, 23, 38, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 17, 13, 23, 37, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 17, 13, 23, 37, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 17, 13, 20, 20, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 20, 8, 30, 2, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 26, 15, 33, 58, tzinfo=tzlocal())]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is for recent s3 list_objectsv2. The boto3 client gives lastModifed in datetime.datetime format, and ways to convert it is as below
links: [boto3 link](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2)
and 
[aws s3 listobj](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html)

```
import datetime
from dateutil.tz import tzutc
# node s3 response '2019-06-17T18:42:57.000Z'
# python boto3 s3 response datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 1, 22, 41, 55, tzinfo=tzutc())
'''  {'ETag': '"c8ba0ad5003832f63690ea8ff9b66052"',
  'Key': 'SOMEFILE',
  'LastModified': datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 2, 18, 50, 47, tzinfo=tzutc()),
  'Size': 6390623,
  'StorageClass': 'STANDARD'}
'''
l = datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 1, 22, 41, 55, tzinfo=tzutc())
get_last_modified = int(l.strftime('%s'))
print(l)
print(get_last_modified)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get last object last modified date like that:

#### With `resource`

```
boto3.resource('s3').Object(<BUCKET_NAME>, <file_path>).last_modified
```

#### With `client`

```
boto3.client('s3').head_object(<BUCKET_NAME>, <file_path>)['LastModified']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import boto3
from boto3.session import Session

session = Session(aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
s3 = session.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME)

for obj in my_bucket.objects.all():
    print('{} | {}'.format(obj.key, obj.last_modified))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try sorting the returned list of objects by `LastModified` key

```
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3_response = s3_client.list_objects(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME)
sorted_contents = sorted(s3_response['Contents'], key=lambda d: d['LastModified'], reverse=True)
sorted_contents[0].get('Key')
```

You can remove `reverse=True` flag in order to get the earliest modified object. You can also sort by `Size` of the objects or any other properties you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I used for my lambda function...

Use `s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=Your_bucket_name)` to list the objects then get the key `LastModified` from the contents.

```py
import boto3
import json
import datetime  
   
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
   bucket = Your-bucket-name
   try:
       listdata = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket)
       contents = listdata['Contents'] if "Contents" in listdata else []
       for key in contents:
       lastmodified = str(key['LastModified'])
       print("lastmodified:", lastmodified)
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the last modified timestamp for the most recently modified object in each S3 bucket along with a check to ensure that the bucket has objects before attempting to find the most recently modified object.

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timezone

# Specify the AWS CLI profile name (optional)
aws_profile = 'your_profile_name'

# Create a boto3 session using the specified profile
session = boto3.Session(profile_name=aws_profile)
s3 = session.client('s3', region_name='eu-west-1')

# List all S3 buckets
buckets = s3.list_buckets()

for bucket_info in buckets['Buckets']:
    bucket_name = bucket_info['Name']

    # List objects in the current bucket
    objects = s3.list_objects(Bucket=bucket_name)

    # Check if there are any objects in the bucket
    if 'Contents' in objects:
        # Find the most recently modified object
        latest_object = max(objects['Contents'], key=lambda obj: obj.get('LastModified', datetime.min))

        # Get the last modified timestamp of the most recently modified object
        last_modified_bucket = latest_object.get('LastModified')

        # Convert last modified timestamp to a human-readable format
        formatted_last_modified_bucket = last_modified_bucket.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z")

        print(f"Bucket: {bucket_name}, Last Modified: {formatted_last_modified_bucket}")
    else:
        print(f"Bucket: {bucket_name} has no objects.")
```