# How to download the latest file of an S3 bucket using Boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

The other questions I could find were refering to an older version of Boto. I would like to download the latest file of an S3 bucket. In the [documentation](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_object_versions) I found that there is a method list_object_versions() that gets you a boolean IsLatest. Unfortunately I only managed to set up a connection and to download a file. Could you please show me how I can extend my code to get the latest file of the bucket? Thank you

```
import boto3
conn = boto3.client('s3',
                    region_name="eu-west-1",
                    endpoint_url="customendpoint",
                    config=Config(signature_version="s3", s3={'addressing_style': 'path'}))
```

From here I dont know how to get the latest added file from a bucket called `mytestbucket`. There are various csv files in the bucket but all of course with a different name.

Update:

```
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config

s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name="eu-west-1", endpoint_url="custom endpoint", aws_access_key_id = '1234', aws_secret_access_key = '1234', config=Config(signature_version="s3", s3={'addressing_style': 'path'}))
my_bucket = s3.Bucket('mytestbucket22')
unsorted = []
for file in my_bucket.objects.filter():
   unsorted.append(file)

files = [obj.key for obj in sorted(unsorted, key=get_last_modified, reverse=True)][0:9]
```

This gives me the following error:

```
NameError: name 'get_last_modified' is not defined
```

Answer (score 32):

Variation of the answer I provided for: [Boto3 S3, sort bucket by last modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44574548/boto3-s3-sort-bucket-by-last-modified). You can modify the code to suit to your needs.

```
get_last_modified = lambda obj: int(obj['LastModified'].strftime('%s'))

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
objs = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket='my_bucket')['Contents']
last_added = [obj['Key'] for obj in sorted(objs, key=get_last_modified)][0]
```

If you want to reverse the sort:

```
[obj['Key'] for obj in sorted(objs, key=get_last_modified, reverse=True)][0]
```

Comment: Thank you. I added my configuration to the client and edited my buckets name but I get the following error: get_last_modified = lambda obj: int(obj['LastModified'].strftime('%s')) ValueError: Invalid format string

Comment: Are you using `Python 2.7` or `Python 3`?

Comment: I'm using 3.6.1.

Comment: I think you should modify `[0]` with `[-1]` if you want the latest added file.

Comment: Do you need to consider pagination if a directory has over 1,000 objects?

Comment: @MattBunch yes, if the bucket has more than 1000 objects, you need to paginate, fetch all objects and then sort.

Comment: One question here.  I am not clear about the overall steps to run this piece of code.   Do you put this lambda and boto3 function in AWS lambda service's function code area or put it in a Python script that run in EC2?  If you put it in AWS lambda, do you need to assign a specific AWS role so it can access S3?  Thanks.

Comment: @user1457659 this has nothing to do with AWS Lambda service. I am using Python lambda function. Should work on any machine that has Python installed and AWS credentials set correctly.

Comment: @jz22 and others. If you are running into the `Invalid format string` error, change the `%s` to `%S` (upper case 'S'). Check out [this](https://github.com/addisonlynch/pyTD/issues/1).

Answer (score 23):

This handles when there are more than 1000 objects in the s3 bucket. This is basically @SaadK answer without the for loop and using newer version for list_objects_v2.

EDIT: Fixes issue @Timothée-Jeannin identified. Ensures that latest across all pages is identified.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Paginator.ListObjectsV2

```py
import boto3

def get_most_recent_s3_object(bucket_name, prefix):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    paginator = s3.get_paginator( "list_objects_v2" )
    page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=prefix)
    latest = None
    for page in page_iterator:
        if "Contents" in page:
            latest2 = max(page['Contents'], key=lambda x: x['LastModified'])
            if latest is None or latest2['LastModified'] > latest['LastModified']:
                latest = latest2
    return latest

latest = get_most_recent_s3_object(bucket_name, prefix)

latest['Key']  # -->   'prefix/objectname'
```

Comment: Isn't this incorrect? If there is multiple page, this will give the most recent object of the last page since it may be redefined at each iteration.

Comment: Just so the next person doesn't have to read carefully/check the edit history: The issue has been fixed

Comment: How could one extend this code to download say the top 10 most recent files? Rather than just the singular most recent file?

Comment: @PrithviBoinpally make latest a list and use some predicate before pushing to the list. The predicate would check if the current list is at capacity or if the current file is newer than the oldest in the list. Adjust the data structures as required if performance benchmarking shows improvements.

Answer (score 22):

You can do

```
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='bucket_name', Prefix='prefix')
all = response['Contents']        
latest = max(all, key=lambda x: x['LastModified'])
```

Comment: Hence, if you are looking out for the latest updated folder, you could go ahead with

`latest['Key'].split('/')[1]`

Comment: It should be noted this will only show the latest object from the first 1000 objects in the bucket.  You'll need to use a paginator if your bucket contains more objects.

Answer (score 10):

If you have a lot of files then you'll need to use pagination as mentioned by helloV. This is how I did it.

```
get_last_modified = lambda obj: int(obj['LastModified'].strftime('%s'))
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
paginator = s3.get_paginator( "list_objects" )
page_iterator = paginator.paginate( Bucket = "BucketName", Prefix = "Prefix")
for page in page_iterator:
    if "Contents" in page:
        last_added = [obj['Key'] for obj in sorted( page["Contents"], key=get_last_modified)][-1]
```

Comment: how can I download the latest file.here it is populating only filename .could please tell me how to get download

Answer (score 3):

This is basically the same answer as helloV in the case you use `Session` as I'm doing.

```
from boto3.session import Session
import settings

session = Session(aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                          aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
s3 = session.resource("s3")

get_last_modified = lambda obj: int(obj.last_modified.strftime('%s'))


bckt = s3.Bucket("my_bucket")
objs = [obj for obj in bckt.objects.all()]

objs = [obj for obj in sorted(objs, key=get_last_modified)]
last_added = objs[-1].key
```

Having `objs` sorted allows you to quickly delete all files but the latest with

```
for obj in objs[:-1]:
    s3.Object("my_bucket", obj.key).delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to download the latest version of the file using default download file command

```
import boto3
import botocore

BUCKET_NAME = 'mytestbucket'
KEY = 'fileinbucket.txt'

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

try:
    s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).download_file(KEY, 'downloadname.txt')
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
    if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
        print("The object does not exist.")
    else:
        raise
```

Reference [link](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/s3-example-download-file.html)

To get the last modified or uploaded file you can use the following

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket('myBucket')
unsorted = []
for file in my_bucket.objects.filter():
   unsorted.append(file)

files = [obj.key for obj in sorted(unsorted, key=get_last_modified, 
    reverse=True)][0:9]
```

As answer in this reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44574548/boto3-s3-sort-bucket-by-last-modified) states, its not the optimal but it works.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe my question was not clear enough. I just edited it and provided more information. I would like to download the latest file from a bucket that contains a couple of csv files and I want to download always the latest no matter what name it has.

Comment: Latest in the sense, not the latest version of a particular file? or the last added file?

Comment: The latest added file.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately this shows me another error. I've put it into my question. Do I have to import something else?

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to download latest file from s3 bucket but located in a specific folder. Use following function to get latest filename using bucket name and prefix (which is folder name).

```
import boto3

def get_latest_file_name(bucket_name,prefix):
    """
    Return the latest file name in an S3 bucket folder.

    :param bucket: Name of the S3 bucket.
    :param prefix: Only fetch keys that start with this prefix (folder  name).
    """
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    objs = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name)['Contents']
    shortlisted_files = dict()            
    for obj in objs:
        key = obj['Key']
        timestamp = obj['LastModified']
        # if key starts with folder name retrieve that key
        if key.startswith(prefix):              
            # Adding a new key value pair
            shortlisted_files.update( {key : timestamp} )   
    latest_filename = max(shortlisted_files, key=shortlisted_files.get)
    return latest_filename

latest_filename = get_latest_file_name(bucket_name='use_your_bucket_name',prefix = 'folder_name/')
```

Comment: this code is returning the latest file but how can I download that file ?

Comment: Too bad `list_objects_v2` only retrieves 1000 items (as it paginates) so this code does not work