# Sort files in IBM cloud object storage

Tags: ibm-cloud, object-storage

I am trying to find a way to sort the files in the cloud object storage as per last modified filter. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Which API or language?

Comment: Language is Python and API is IBM Cloud Object Storage

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44574548/boto3-s3-sort-bucket-by-last-modified

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Boto3 S3, sort bucket by last modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44574548/boto3-s3-sort-bucket-by-last-modified)