# How to get the last modify time for a file in s3 with python boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

Just as the title said.How can I use python-boto3 to get the last modify time for a file in amazon-s3? Thanks.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679344/how-can-i-get-last-modified-datetime-of-s3-objects-with-boto

Answer (score 2):

In boto3, you can use [s3.client.head_object()](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.head_object)

this will return a dict of meta data for the particular object. You just need to look into the LastModified element.

```
'LastModified': datetime(2015, 1, 1)
```