# Can I get metadata of files reading by Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Let's suppose we have 2 files, file#1 created at 12:55 and file#2 created at 12:58. While reading these two files I want to add a new column "creation_time". Rows  belong to file#1 have 12:55 in "creation_time" column and Rows belong to file#2 have 12:58 in "creation_time".

```
new_data = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("s3://bucket7838-1/input")
```

I'm using above code snippet to read the files in "input" directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use **`input_file_name()`** function to get the filename and then use **`hdfs file api`** to get the file timestamp finally join both dataframes on **`filename`**.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
URI           = sc._gateway.jvm.java.net.URI
Path          = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
FileSystem    = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
Configuration = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration

fs = FileSystem.get(URI("hdfs://<namenode_address>:8020"), Configuration())

status = fs.listStatus(Path('<hdfs_directory>'))

filestatus_df=spark.createDataFrame([[str(i.getPath()),i.getModificationTime()/1000] for i in status],["filename","modified_time"]).\
withColumn("modified_time",to_timestamp(col("modified_time")))

input_df=spark.read.csv("<hdfs_directory>").\
withColumn("filename",input_file_name())

#join both dataframes on filename to get filetimestamp
df=input_df.join(filestatus_df,['filename'],"left")
```

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful answer. SO must have an option to upvote twice :-)

Comment: @Shu, source is AWS S3.

Comment: Wonderful Answer :)
Thanks Shu

Comment: Is there any api like creation_date_file() which gives creation_date of file as well as we have input_file_name()?

Comment: @AbdulHaseeb, `No` Spark is not yet supporting that feature, we need to still use hdfs filestatus api to get metadata info! https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileStatus.html

Comment: Okay. Anyways your solution helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps

1. Use sparkcontext.wholeTextFiles("/path/to/folder/containing/all/files")
2. The above returns an RDD where key is the path of the file, and value is the content of the file
3. rdd.map(lambda x:x[1]) - this give you an rdd with only file contents
4. rdd.map(lambda x: customeFunctionToProcessFileContent(x))
5. since map function works in parallel, any operations you do, would be faster and not sequential - as long as your tasks don't depend on each other, which is the main criteria for parallelism

```
import os
import time

import pyspark
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import *

# reading all the files to create PairRDD 
input_rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles("file:///home/user/datatest/*",2)

#convert RDD to DF

input_df=spark.createDataFrame(input_rdd)

input_df.show(truncate=False)
'''
+---------------------------------------+------------+
|_1                                     |_2          |
+---------------------------------------+------------+
|file:/home/user/datatest/test.txt      |1,2,3  1,2,3|
|file:/home/user/datatest/test.txt1     |4,5,6  6,7,6|
+---------------------------------------+------------+
'''
input_df.select("_2").take(2)
#[Row(_2=u'1,2,3\n1,2,3\n'), Row(_2=u'4,5,6\n6,7,6\n')]


# function to get a creation time of a file
def time_convesion(filename):
    return time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(filename.split(":")[1]))

#udf registration
time_convesion_udf = udf(time_convesion, StringType())

#udf apply over the DF
final_df = input_df.withColumn("created_time", time_convesion_udf(input_df['_1']))

final_df.show(2,truncate=False)
'''
+---------------------------------------+------------+------------------------+
|_1                                     |_2          |created_time            |
+---------------------------------------+------------+------------------------+
|file:/home/user/datatest/test.txt      |1,2,3  1,2,3|Sat Jul 11 18:31:03 2020|
|file:/home/user/datatest/test.txt1     |4,5,6  6,7,6|Sat Jul 11 18:32:43 2020|
+---------------------------------------+------------+------------------------+
'''
# proceed with the next steps for the implementation
```

The above works with default partition though. So you might not get input files count equal to output file count(as output is number of partitions).

You can re-partition the RDD based on count or any other unique value based on your data, so you end up with output files count equal to input count. This approach will have only parallelism but will not have the performance achieved with optimal number of partitions

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this solution.
Is there any possible solution using dataframes?

Comment: and in the above solution where i'm getting creation time of file ?

Comment: write an UDF for getting a creation time for each row you process. you can process files one by one and pass it to UDF and spark load it too.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679344/how-can-i-get-last-modified-datetime-of-s3-objects-with-boto OR the below code is for reading it from NAS
```import os
path = '/home/user/datatest/'
files = []
# r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if '.txt' in file:
            files.append(os.path.join(r, file))
for f in files:
    print(f)
    time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(f))
```

Comment: spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("s3://bucket7838-1/input")
this reads all the files from the directory, who will I know that which row belongs to which file ?

Comment: You want me to read files one by one and getting theri metadata using boto3 ?

Comment: Yes Abdul, If your data size is small then you can use this one by one read approach(I used to do it for near real time spark streaming jobs). but If you have huge volume of data then you can find the approach in the above answer.

Comment: Actually I have data in TBs to process

Comment: Thanks sathiyara, Can you provide some links which can give me some help in implementing above solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217665/discussion-between-abdul-haseeb-and-sathiyarajan).

Comment: Add the end we have three columns, one is text file, 2nd is data and 3rd is creation_data. I want output like this


column_1, column_2, column_3,            creation_date
      1              2                3              Sat Jul 11 18:31:03 2020
      1              2                3              Sat Jul 11 18:31:03 2020
      4              5                6              Sat Jul 11 18:32:43 2020
      4              5                6              Sat Jul 11 18:32:43 2020

Answer (score 0):

Assuming file modification time is good enough, this is now exposed since [spark 3.2.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-37273) using the hidden `_metadata` struct column that has the following schema

```
_metadata: struct (nullable = false)
 |-- file_path: string (nullable = false)
 |-- file_name: string (nullable = false)
 |-- file_size: long (nullable = false)
 |-- file_block_start: long (nullable = false)
 |-- file_block_length: long (nullable = false)
 |-- file_modification_time: timestamp (nullable = false)
```

The [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/en/ingestion/file-metadata-column.html#file-metadata-column) state that the struct schema is unstable and may change in future releases.

Your query might then look something like

```
spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("s3://bucket7838-1/input")
.withColumn("file_modification_time", "_metadata.file_modification_time")
.filter(...)
```